# how to create a simple image test

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to create a test image like the following image for my propose in `matlab`. but I have no idea how to make this.

[image]

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a1= 256; b1= 256; %% big square size
a2 = 200;b2 = 200; %% small square size
r = a1/4;  %% cicle radius
shape1 = zeros(a1,b1);
shape2 = rgb2gray(insertShape(shape1,'FilledRectangle',[0.5*(a1-a2) 0.5*(b1-b2) a2 b2],'Opacity',0.5));
shape3 = rgb2gray(insertShape(shape2,'FilledCircle',[a1/2 b1/2 r],'Opacity',1));
imshow(shape3)
```

Comment: you did not mention the size of each square or the circle, I just randomly chose some values. You can change based on what you want.